# Silverlight CliptoBound property issue

Tags: silverlight

I am working on a Silverlight application and my problem is like this: I have a `WrapPanel`
and inside the `WrapPanel` I am adding a number of images. Then, I rotate these images either 
by 90 degrees or -90 degrees.

So if my image size is 200 by 250, when I rotate it it will go out of the `WrapPanel` by 50 pixels. Is there a way to clip this image to the WrapPanel's actual bounds?

Comment: I am looking also measurement of hieght and width let say if I have hieght 600 and width 600 then it will give me space 600*600 how i can measure.

Comment: Are all the images in the panel the same size?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds to me like you are using the RenderTransform to rotate the image.  The problem is the transform is applied after the size and position of the image has been allocated hence the rotated image bleads outside of its original rectangle.

One solution is to use the `LayoutTransfomer` to effect that transform instead.  This would cause the WrapPanel to re-flow the elements even moving the image to the next row. Here is an example using rectangles for simplicity:-

```
    <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{StaticResource TestData}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <toolkit:WrapPanel />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <toolkit:LayoutTransformer RenderTransformOrigin="0.5, 0.5" Margin="5">
                        <toolkit:LayoutTransformer.LayoutTransform  >
                            <RotateTransform Angle="0" />
                        </toolkit:LayoutTransformer.LayoutTransform>
                        <Rectangle Width="100" Height="150" Fill="Blue" MouseLeftButtonUp="Rectangle_MouseLeftButtonUp"  />
                    </toolkit:LayoutTransformer>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
    </ScrollViewer>
```

I've added code-behind:-

```
    private void Rectangle_MouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        LayoutTransformer lt = ((FrameworkElement)sender).Parent as LayoutTransformer;
        RotateTransform rt = (RotateTransform)lt.LayoutTransform;
        rt.Angle += 90;
        lt.ApplyLayoutTransform();
    }
```

My `TestData` items source is an arbitary `List<T>`, doesn't really matter what is in the list just that it contains a few items.

**Using the ScrollViewer as dynamic clipping region**

Note that its normal to place a WrapPanel in a `ScrollViewer` which naturally clips its content anywar.

Perhaps you really do want to clip the WrapPanel and you don't want any scrolling.  Obviously you could apply a `RectangleGeometry` its `Clip` property but you would have to ensure the clip rectangle always matched the actual size of the `WrapPanel`.  You could do that by monitoring its `SizeChanged` event and using a bit of code.

Another approach is to put it in a `ScrollViewer` then disable both scroll bars.

Comment: +1 good answer, plus see my additional answer below to simplify the clipping.

Comment: Dear AnthonyWJones I have one usercontrol and this user control I am adding as image into wrappanel.select image And I am click on vertical and horizontal button at that time it will ratote. so how I can implement this.

Comment: @Jitendra:  I'm not sure how much of that you want me to describe how to implement.  I'm also not sure how the terms "vertical" and "horizontal" apply to rotation,  are you sure you don't mean rotate clockwise and anti-clockwise?  You could use the `MouseLeftButtonUp` as in my example but instead of rotating you could simple store the `LayoutTransformer` in a field.  Then the clicks on your buttons could modify the `LayoutTransform` property of the field as you see fit.

Answer (score 2):

Just to add to AnthonyWJones answer above, which is entirely correct, you need to rotate during layout rather than render. Silverlight Panels do not clip their contents, in order to perform clipping you must set their Clip property to the required geometry manually.

The following blog post provides an attached behaviour that will automatically clip the bounds of a panel:

http://www.scottlogic.co.uk/blog/colin/2009/05/silverlight-cliptobounds-can-i-clip-it-yes-you-can/

You simply set the property as follows:

```
    <Canvas util:Clip.ToBounds="true"
            Grid.Column="1"  Background="Aqua" Margin="20" >
        <Ellipse Fill="Red" Canvas.Top="-10"
                 Canvas.Left="-10" Width="130" Height="130"/>
    </Canvas>
```